# Capture Images With Intent without clicking the camera button again

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I want to capture images through Intent

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

but the problem is that with this code the camera is  started and the user has to click on the camera button to capture the image , but what i want is that the camera sholud start and take picture without any furthur interaction with the user

I want to do this using INTENT

Answer (score 1):

That is the way I did it : 
Declare an instance of Camera, and SurfaceHolder.

Create an Object CallBackPicture, and implements the method on PictureTaken (method launched when you want to take a picture)

```
                 mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);  
                 Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()  
                 {     
                     @Override  
                     public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)  
                    {
                                             //DO YOUR STUFF
                    }
                };  

               // Open the instance of camera
               mCamera = Camera.open();
               try {
               // Call the preview (not sure if it is working without this call
               mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
               mCamera.startPreview();
               } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               }

               if(mCamera == null) Log.i(TAG, "mCamera is null");
               // Will call the onPictureTaken implemented above
               // Look at the documentation : public final void takePicture 

               mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);  
               mCamera.stopPreview();
               mCamera.release();
```

By modifying this, you should be able to do what you want..
Don't forget to modify the Manifest.XML too, but I think you've already done it!

EDIT : sometimes there is some problem with stoppreview() and release()..
So, the thing i've done is :

```
if (mCamera != null) {
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}
mCamera = Camera.open();
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. There are only two options:

1. Invoking Camera app via Intent. The user then uses Camera app in normal way - i.e. presses the button when ready.
2. Use [`Camera`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) class - this is much more work compared to running Camera app via Intent. But it gives you full control.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the camera intent you basically "run" the camera app (or other app that registered on this intent), so basically, you can't control of how it works.
You can use the Camera API...take a look [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx)